# How to run Robotium Automation Test Cases in Multiple Devices

Tags: unit-testing, build-automation, junit4, robotium

I have my test scripts ready which work in single device.. Now i have to run my testcases in multiple device.. Is there any solution for that.. or i have to use any build tool for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the devices you want to test to the adb server, then in your test scripts target each device:

```
adb -s <devices ip>:<port>
```

You could be smart about how you cycle through the connected devices, by making it generic in your script.